# Haystack/Whoosh search for email address with at symbol?

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using a simple out-of-the-box Django/Haystack/Whoosh setup only for autocomplete purposes and everything works fine except for trying to search for an email address.  If I type in `joe`, I will get all the objects whose names/email addresses start with `joe`, but if I type in `joe@`, I don't get only the objects with `joe@` email addresses.  It's as if the `@` symbol is being ignored, whether I escape it or not.  I cannot find anything in Haystack help or anywhere on the web.  How do I get Haystack (or is it Whoosh?) to recognize the `@` symbol?

```
...
class ContactIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    full_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='full_name', null=True)
    email = indexes.CharField(model_attr='email', null=True)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look inside QueryParser in [whoosh/qparser/default.py](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/src/74dc6350fbcad97eae278bea4ec5dcafd2a308c2/src/whoosh/qparser/default.py?at=default#cl-38)

haystack don't parse query string by itself
[whoosh_backend.py#L370](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py#L370)